# Netflix zuul : Configure a TLS pass through HTTP CONNECT calls for outbound proxy server like squid

Tags: java, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Problem statement;

I wanted to establish a connection to outer internet through a proxy server. I am using Zuul as gateway which is configured with system parameters like https.proxyHost/https.proxyPort variables with appropriate values, but Zuul is creating a TLS termination connection to proxy server.

How do I configure Zuul to create a Pass through connection so the request would become opaque in proxy server no body should be able to tamper the same.

Any help would be appreciated
Cheers
Anant

Comment: I don't know if that is possible. Because zuul is in maintenance mode it won't get added if not.

Comment: Any workaround you could suggest

Comment: None. You could write a filter, but it wouldn't be trivial